# model binding with controller function laravel routing

Tags: php, laravel-5

hello I'm using laravel 5.4, and I would use a model binding in my routing.
But I would use a controller function:

```
Route::get('/user/{id}', 'usersController@show');
```

But I would use a model binding so in my controller I would do something like:

```
public function show(Request $request, User $user){
    dd($user->id)
}
```

But now `$user->id` is null because I don't know how binding model and use a controller function. 
I tried with:

```
Route::model('user', 'User');
```

But It doesn't work.

Is it possible?

Comment: Well the first thing is wrong in your route, `Route::get('/user/{id}', 'usersController@show');` should be `Route::get('/user/{user}', 'usersController@show');`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well from the Laravel Manual you don't need the `Route::model('user', 'User');`, Laravel does that for you :

> Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or
>   controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route
>   segment name.

So just change this line:

```
Route::get('/user/{user}', 'usersController@show');
```

And since you're using the type hint for the variable, Laravel will automatically bind it to the user model.